# Botium - Need help to configure spec file for Amazon Alexa

Tags: javascript, bots, chatbot

**What modifications should i do to run the same for Alexa**

I need to run convo files through individual spec files like the same example which is given in botium-core project.Since I find it difficult to configure the spec file for Alexa for which no examples where given in Botium-core

Botium spec setup for Amazon Alexa like botium core's fillScriptingMemoryFromFile.spec.js

Convos folder
• Contains 2 files
1.product.xlsx  - product1  Wiener Schnitzel
2. buy.convo

```
Examplefile.spec

Note - I want the configuration for Amazon.In botium core its not give for Alexa

const path = require('path')
const assert = require('chai').assert
const BotDriver = require('../../../').BotDriver
const Capabilities = require('../../../').Capabilities

const echoConnector = ({ queueBotSays }) => {
  return {
    UserSays (msg) {
      const botMsg = { sender: 'bot', sourceData: msg.sourceData, messageText: `You said: ${msg.messageText}` }
      queueBotSays(botMsg)
    }
  }

describe('scripting.scriptingmemory.memoryenabled.originalkept', function () {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    const myCaps = {
      [Capabilities.PROJECTNAME]: 'scripting.scriptingmemory', // "my project name here i've given" . Is this correct ??
      [Capabilities.CONTAINERMODE]: echoConnector, // "alexa-smapi",
      [Capabilities.SCRIPTING_XLSX_SHEETNAMES_SCRIPTING_MEMORY]: 'ScriptingMemory', // What should I give here ??
      [Capabilities.SCRIPTING_XLSX_SHEETNAMES]: 'Convos', // What should I give here ??
      [Capabilities.SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY]: true,
      [Capabilities.SCRIPTING_MEMORYEXPANSION_KEEP_ORIG]: true

    }
    const driver = new BotDriver(myCaps)
    this.compiler = driver.BuildCompiler()
    this.container = await driver.Build()
  })
  afterEach(async function () {
    this.container && await this.container.Clean()
  })

  it('Original convo kept', async function () {
    this.compiler.ReadScriptsFromDirectory(path.resolve(__dirname, 'convosSimple')) // This is the folder in which i have convo file
    this.compiler.ExpandScriptingMemoryToConvos()
    assert.equal(this.compiler.convos.length, 2) // why 2 ???
  })
})
```

Finally we run the spec using mocha run "spec file name"
I need help to configure this so that i can create individual test run for each scenario under "scripts tag" in package.json .So When i have 10 intents i can categorise each a unique spec name and use "mocha specname"

Answer (score 0):

For connecting Botium to Alexa SMAPI, you can find setup instructions and the capabilities to use in the [connector repository](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-smapi/)

The *SCRIPTING_XLSX-...* capabilities are instructions how Botium should read excel files - more information in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48922649/Composing+in+Excel+files)

For what you want to do, I recommend taking a look at [botium-bindings](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-bindings), it is the "glue" between Botium and test runners as Jasmine, Mocha, Jest. There is even a sample available for [splitting convos in multiple folders](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-bindings/tree/master/samples/utterances):

You can have a file spec/scenario1.spec.js

```
const BotiumBindings = require('botium-bindings')
const bb = new BotiumBindings({ convodirs: [ './spec/scenario1' ] })
BotiumBindings.helper.jest().setupJestTestSuite({ bb })
```

And another one spec/scenario2.spec.js

```
const BotiumBindings = require('botium-bindings')
const bb = new BotiumBindings({ convodirs: [ './spec/scenario2' ] })
BotiumBindings.helper.jest().setupJestTestSuite({ bb })
```

Comment: Thanks florian .I'll get back 2 you soon with my results